# Rails/SQL: How can I query topics that a user doesn't have a post?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models/tables:

> Topic has many Posts, Post belongs to User.

So using Rails query or raw SQL, how can I select all Topics that a specific user doesn't have a Post in?

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
Topic.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON posts.topic_id = topics.id").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id").where("users.id IS NULL")
```